# I am building multiple checkboxes. I want to add the functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays, html

I am building multiple checkboxes. I want to add the functionality, where in a group one checkbox only one checkbox should checked with right or wrong value. After selecting all the groups submit button should be enables.After clicking on submit button, value of each group should (right or wrong answer) should be displayed.How should I go about doing that ?

```js
function isChecked(checkbox, sub1) {
    document.getElementById(sub1).disabled = !checkbox.checked;
}


$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $box.prop("checked", true);
        //alert("checked");

    } else {
        $box.prop("checked", false);
    }

    var bool;
    $("input.checkbox").change(function() {
        bool = $(".checkbox:not(:checked)").length != 6;

        // enable/disable
        $("#submitbutton").prop('disabled', bool).addClass('btn');

        // $("#submitbutton").removeAttr("disabled", bool).addClass("btn");
        //$('#submitbutton').removeClass('btn1').prop(':disabled', bool).addClass('btn');
        <!--  alert('right')-->
    }).change('color');


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button0" name="fooby[0][]" value="chk0" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button1" name="fooby[0][]" value="chk0" />
<br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button2" name="fooby[1][]" value="chk1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button3" name="fooby[1][]" value="chk2" /><br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button4" name="fooby[2][]" value="chk3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button5" name="fooby[2][]" value="chk4" />
<br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button6" name="fooby[3][]" value="chk5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button7" name="fooby[3][]" value="chk6" />
<br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button8" name="fooby[4][]" value="chk7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button9" name="fooby[4][]" value="chk8" />
<br>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button10" name="fooby[5][]" value="chk9" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button11" name="fooby[5][]" value="chk10" /> <br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled" class="btn" />
```

Comment: "in a group one checkbox only one checkbox should checked with right or wrong value" -- why not use radio buttons? Then no JavaScript would be needed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your question Blazemonger. In my whole  project i use only check box. so i preferred to kept as same.

Comment: @ArunJack From a UX point of view thats a very bad way of designing your site.

Comment: That's not a good reason. If I understand you correctly, the functionality you're describing is exactly what radio buttons do. There's also the question of UX (user experience) -- users would see the checkboxes (squares) instead of radio buttons (circles) and expect a certain behavior.

Comment: @Blazemonger  Thanks, if its radio buttons whether is this functionality is possible?

Comment: it's a bit crazy idea, but can use a switch button for do it (how [http://bootstrapswitch.com/examples.html](http://bootstrapswitch.com/examples.html) or [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch))

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the comments you can use `RadioButton` instead of `Checkbox` this will handle for your the checking stuffs. However, to enable the `submit` button you have to do some maths, by verifying if the number of the checked radio buttons is the half of the total number of the radio buttons:

```
if($("input[type='radio']").length/2==$("input[type='radio']:checked").length)
{
$(".btn").prop("disabled","");
}
```

Finally, here is a demo:

```js
$("input[type='radio']").on("change",function(){
if($("input[type='radio']").length/2==$("input[type='radio']:checked").length)
{
$(".btn").prop("disabled","");
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button0" name="fooby[0][]" value="chk0" />   
   <input type="radio"  class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button1" name="fooby[0][]" value="chk0" />
     <br>

    <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button2" name="fooby[1][]" value="chk1"  /> 
    <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1"  id="button3" name="fooby[1][]" value="chk2" /><br>

   <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button4" name="fooby[2][]" value="chk3" />   
   <input type="radio"  class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button5" name="fooby[2][]" value="chk4" />
     <br>

     <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button6" name="fooby[3][]" value="chk5" />   
   <input type="radio"  class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button7" name="fooby[3][]" value="chk6" />
          <br>

     <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button8" name="fooby[4][]" value="chk7" />   
   <input type="radio"  class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button9" name="fooby[4][]" value="chk8" />
               <br>

     <input type="radio" class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button10" name="fooby[5][]" value="chk9" />   
   <input type="radio"  class="checkbox checkbox_1" id="button11" name="fooby[5][]" value="chk10" /> <br>
    
 <input type="submit" value="Submit"  id="submitbutton" disabled="disabled" class="btn"/>
```

Comment: After submitting, i cant able to see the write or wrong  answer value..

Comment: @ArunJack it's depending on how you retrieve your data in the second page, and I don't have the code of this page, so I can't handle what's is displayed in the other side. I juste made the code working as described in Your question

Comment: But i didn't get what i expected answer, actually if i select any one checkbox in each group depending upon value checked by user, value of each group should calculate , once its click on submit button answer should display

Answer (score 0):

```
<FORM NAME=MAIN>

<SCRIPT>

HTML = [];
function PRINT(L, X) { HTML.push(L.split("#").join(X)); }
function FLUSH() { document.write(HTML.join("")); HTML = []; }

COOKIE = "ANSWERS";
function SetCookie(NAME, VALUE) { var E = new Date(); E.setFullYear(E.getFullYear() + 5); document.cookie = NAME + "=" + VALUE + ";Expires=" + E.toGMTString(); }
function GetCookie(NAME) { var i, e, s, K = document.cookie.split(";"); for (i = 0; i < K.length; i++) { for (s = 0; K[i].charCodeAt(s) < 33; s++); e = K[i].indexOf("="); if (K[i].substring(s, e) == NAME) return K[i].slice(++e); } return ""; }

BOX_COLOR = "0033CC";
TEXT_COLOR = "FFFFFF";
ROW_COLORS = "111133 333355".split(" ");
Q = "Do you speak English?|Do you have an Apple iPhone X ?|Do you write JavaScript?|Have you ever caught an alligator?|Did you eat it?|Do you like winter?|Is the earth big?|Zero equals false. Agree?|Does your laptop run on 19 volts?".split("|");

ANSWER = GetCookie(COOKIE);
if (ANSWER && ANSWER != null) ANSWER = ANSWER.split(","); else ANSWER = [];
for (i = ANSWER.length; i < Q.length; i++) ANSWER.push(0);

PRINT("<TABLE CELLSPACING=1 CELLPADDING=7 BGCOLOR=#>", BOX_COLOR);
PRINT("<TR><TD>#True<TD>#False<TD>#Questions", "<FONT COLOR=" + TEXT_COLOR + ">");
for (i = 0; i < Q.length; i++)
{
  PRINT("<TR BGCOLOR=#>", ROW_COLORS[i&1]);
  PRINT("<TD><CENTER><INPUT "+(ANSWER[i]==1?"CHECKED":"")+" NAME=X#A TYPE=CHECKBOX onClick='K(#, 1);'>", i);
  PRINT("<TD><CENTER><INPUT "+(ANSWER[i]==2?"CHECKED":"")+" NAME=X#B TYPE=CHECKBOX onClick='K(#, 2);'>", i);
  PRINT("<TD onClick='K(#, 0);'><FONT COLOR="+TEXT_COLOR+">"+(i+1)+". " + Q[i], i);
}
PRINT("</TABLE><P>");
PRINT("<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE=' Get Answers ' onClick='alert(ANSWER);'>");
PRINT("<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON VALUE=' Delete Answers ' onClick='DeleteAnswers();'>");
PRINT("<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON "+(isComplete()?"":"DISABLED")+" NAME=NEXT VALUE=' NEXT ' onClick='Next();' onMouseOver='CheckAnswers();'>");
FLUSH();

function K(N, V)  // Click event handler
{
  var A = 1;
  if (ANSWER[N] == 1 || (ANSWER[N] == 0 && V == 2)) A = 0;
  ANSWER[N] = (A) ? 1 : 2;
  eval("document.MAIN.X"+N+"A.checked = A;");
  eval("document.MAIN.X"+N+"B.checked = !A;");

  CheckAnswers();
  SaveAnswers();
}

function isComplete() { for (var i = 0; i < Q.length; i++) if (ANSWER[i] == 0) return 0; return 1; }

function AllowNext() { document.MAIN.NEXT.disabled = false; }

function CheckAnswers() { if (isComplete()) AllowNext(); }

function Next() { location.href = "http://www.msn.com"; }

function SaveAnswers() { SetCookie(COOKIE, ANSWER.join(",")); }

function DeleteAnswers()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < Q.length; i++)
  {
    ANSWER[i] = 0;
    eval("document.MAIN.X"+i+"A.checked = false;");
    eval("document.MAIN.X"+i+"B.checked = false;");
  }
  document.MAIN.NEXT.disabled = true;
  SetCookie(COOKIE, "");
}

</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Code-only answers are frowned upon here, so it's always a good idea to include an explanation of HOW this helps the OP.